# Flex: cannot resize player back from Full Screen

Tags: apache-flex

The key event is not listened by my Flex app. Since it is really simple code, I cannot understand where the problem is...

```
init() {

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, escHandler);

}

private function escHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {

    debugF.text = "ESC pressed";


}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but a lot of the user interaction events (including keyboard) are disabled when Flash is in fullscreen mode.  Escape is automatically handled by Flash to exit out of fullscreen.  I don't believe it will be passed to your listeners.

Comment: OH, so keyboard doesn't work in full screen mode. This is the answer.